# Read next line in Jinja2

Tags: file, flask, jinja2

I have a text file with the following format:

```
Title
\n
Description
\n
Title
\n
Description
...
```

In my flask application, I'm sending the reference to the file while rendering my template. I'm able to execute the following code to iterate through the file line by line

```
{% for line in file: %}
    {% set title = line %}
    ....
```

However, I can't use the line

```
{% file.readline() %}
```

because I get the error

```
Encountered unknown tag 'file'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.
```

I checked all my tags and the loops are closed. Is there any way in Jinja to skip a line while reading through a file?

Comment: `{{ file.readline() }}`

Comment: read the [synopsis](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#synopsis) carefully :D

Comment: Yess! Thanks so much, that seemed to work but now I'm getting the error Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There is no colon (`:`) at the end of Jinja controls, they are not the same as Python blocks.

`file.readline()` is an expression, not a Jinja control.  Use `{{ }}`, not `{% %}` to delimit expressions.

Calling `file.readline()` doesn't make sense when also iterating over the file line by line.  You've already read the line by iterating.

```
{% for line in file %}
    {{ line }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```